# Pass parameters for node access on RESTful call

Tags: 7, services

I'm trying to figure out how to pass a filter parameter on a Services rest call.  I've got a node of a specific type that I'd like to access through the Services module and rest.  I'm testing with FireFox RestClient and I can get all nodes of the particular type by typing

```
http://localhost/drupal/gpa/node/?parameters[type]=node_type
```

But, I'd like to be able to get **one** specific instance of 'node_type' that contains a specific field value.  I've taken a look at [node_resource.inc](http://api.drupalhelp.net/api/services/resources--node_resource.inc/7.3), but, I can't seem to make heads or tails of what I need to use as parameters.  I've tried several variations that typically return no result, or, all instances of, 'node_type'.

Is it possible to filter the returned results, or, is my approach incorrect?

**EDIT**: If any C# programmer stumbles across this, I was able to use the Basic HTTP Authentication module to prevent unauthorized access to the view.  First, as Tyler indicated, I needed to change the permissions settings.  In My case, I chose a Role (Administrator).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The entity index resources unfortunately cannot be used to filter by field values, they can only filter by entity property values (e.g. node nid, title, type, etc). I think you have two options:

1. create a custom service resource that uses parameters and a database query (or entity field query) to filter and return what you want
2. use views_json (a sub module of views_datasource) to create a View with a contextual filter for your field

Comment: Tyler, thanks for the direction.  I used #2 above and it worked fine.  However, it does seem a bit insecure.  Do you know if there is a way to secure the resulting view path so that only an admin can execute it?  In actuality, I'm consuming the Rest call from a C# program, so, I'm a bit concerned that anyone can run the query given the path to the view.

Comment: You're welcome. You can secure the View path just like you do for a regular View. On the View's configuration form, go to `Page Settings -> Access`, then decide what type of access control you'd like to apply to the path (e.g. Permission, Role, etc).